# I removed the rear panel of my oven and the cladding is burned

Tags: electrical, oven

i have a similar issue with my oven, I just replaced the fan element and also discovered black burn/scorched areas on the insulation cladding. Is this a worry or normal? Oven is about 15 years old.

Comment: Is it a self cleaning type of oven?

Comment: Model #? Pictures?

Comment: "Similar issue"? similar to what?